# Как поменять локаль для csv файла

Tags: php, csv

Суть в том, что нужно .csv файлом заполнить массив, чтоб загрузить его в базу, но для этого надо поставить локаль 1251. , а это в итоге приводит к тому, что у меня [image]этот хаос

```
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'rus_RUS.CP1251');
   if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    if($_FILES['file']['name'])
    {
        $filename = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']);

        if($filename[1] == 'csv')
        {
            $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");
             while($data = fgetcsv($handle))
            {
                $lines[] = $data;
            }

            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($lines);
            echo '</pre>';
        } 
}
}
```

[image]Вот что в кодировке 1251

[image] а вот utf-8

Comment: Ренат Калинджев Выкладывайте Ваш код текстом, а не картинкой. Во-вторых выложите пример текста, который вставляете в файл. Вы уверены, что это cp1251, а не utf? В каком формате сам файл, в который записываете? От всего этого зависит и способ решения Вашей проблемы.

Comment: Исправил, формат csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в Ваш скрипт `header`

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=cp-1251');
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное. Очень сильно помогли.

Answer (score -1):

либо конвертируйте то что прочитали из файла в utf8. setlocale которую вы используете к сырым данным никак не применимо.

```
print_r(iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8',$lines));
```